# Converting from MultiPolygon to Polygon in PostGIS

Tags: postgis, polygon, geometry, convert, multi-polygon

I have a table in PostGIS, where the data is currently stored as a MultiPolygon. Each Multipolygon has only a single Polygon in it.

How do I query and get the containing Polygon, and not MultiPolygon? I am ok ignoring the Edge case where there are Multiple Polygons in the Multi-Polygon Geometry. All I need is the first or only Polygon in that Geometry.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you want to Ignore the edge cases, and get only the First (or only) Polygon, from the MultiPolygon geometry, then you need to use the [`ST_GeometryN()`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_GeometryN.html) function.

A query like the following will give you the geometry as Polygons

```sql
SELECT ST_GeometryN(geom, 1)
FROM polygons;
```

Comment: the issue with the `(ST_Dump(geom)).geom` type of query, is that you get multiple rows, and need to use it in a subquery, if you want to get just the first Polygon.